# Will this honey pot work?

Tags: honeypot

I just made my first super simple honey pot and am wondering if it will even work:

1. An input field floated -9999 left won't be visible to most humans.  And there's a note saying "Don't write here" if they do see it.
2. An "onChange" event listens for change to that field and when it changes, it alerts ('You're spamming me!') and then redirects to Google.

I am wondering if this is too designed with a human in mind.  Do bots fill the entire form out at one instant?  Would a bot still be able to fill the form out if there's an alert on the page?  Can I force the entity that's using the page to click the "OK" on the alert, effectively causing the bot to wait forever?

I am sure there are hugely robust systems that are out there but I'm looking for something very simple.  I don't get so much spam that I can't handle it...just am frustrated winnowing through 300 spams each month trying to find the one or two new users who actually signed up.

Thank you for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes and no. Some bots will maybe fall for it and fill out everything, but others won't.

Redirecting with JavaScript doesn't sound like a very good idea, because most bots haven't got a JavaScript engine. You could use this fact to filter them - although you could also filter legitimate users.

You may also check how long it takes to get the user fill out the form - if it's too short, it's probably a bot.

Don't expect a 100% success rate, but a combination of techniques may already help a lot.

Comment: One problem is that the CMS (Expression Engine) isn't open source and has miserable forums that are almost never answered promptly -- I don't think I have any access to the server side in this case.  Unless I can maybe somehow add a field and make it required AND make it have to equal null or something.

Comment: @user1149499 In that case you should have a look into the manual of Expression Engine. There are some [methods for spam prevention](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/security/spam_protection.html) otherwise you may check if [writing an add-on may help you](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/add-ons.html).